# How to use flask's ProxyFix middleware with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, flask, google-cloud-functions, werkzeug

Using Firebase or Google Cloud Functions for Python, I'd like to have automatic handling of hostname and remote ip address that goes through Google's proxies, so that my code doesn't need to handle the parsing and logic for the X-Forwarded-* headers.

ProxyFix in general seems to do that for plain vanilla Flask applications via WSGI:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/deploying/proxy_fix/

But since GCF automatically serves a Flask request to the function, ProxyFix doesn't seem to be a possibility.

An additional note is that I use flask's test_request_context feature in order to wrap the given flask request into my flask application object, as shown here:
https://github.com/av1m/functions-multiple-endpoints/blob/main/functions_wrapper/__init__.py

Are there any solutions already implemented for this use-case so that the application developer doesn't need to reinvent the wheel?